# WAMP - PHP/MySQL - Why is my POST call getting mangled

Tags: php, mysql, variables, wamp

EDIT: Mangling is fixed - primary issue appears to be the php/mysql connection

In an attempt to learn how to use a MySQL db on a webpage, I'm following a basic tutorial for connecting to a MySQL instance via PHP (all managed through WAMP2)

The tutorial: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4 uses a PHP_SELF method (that I understand is now depreciated).

I've tried a few other suggestions that I've found doted around, but I can't find resolution to the following error I see in the apache log:

```
(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map POST /%3C$SEARCH.PHP%3E HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/search.php
```

This error prevents the HTML page from being returned, and I get a 403 error in my browser

It appears that this line of HTML/PHP is the culprit:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
```

I have seen suggestions that say to either turn on short_open_tag (a bad idea according to some), change the

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

I can't get any of these methods to work, and wondered if anyone could let me know what dumb thing I've missed this time...

The whole php file I am using is:

```
<?php 
// // This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
 if ($searching =="yes") 
 { 
 echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

 //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
 if ($find == "") 
 { 
 echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
 exit; 
 } 

 include("dbinfo.php");
 mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 

 //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo $result['Item1']; 
 echo " "; 
 echo $result['Item2']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little  message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
 } 
 ?> 


 <h2>Search</h2> 
 <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
 Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
 <Select NAME="field">
 <Option VALUE="item1">Item1</option>
 <Option VALUE="item2">Item2</option>
 </Select>
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
 </form>
```

Comment: What is the name of the PHP file? If it has spaces or special characters, rename it to something simple like "test.php" and try again.

Comment: Just look at the html code of the generated page and tell us what is written at `action="<?=$PHP_SELF?"` in both cases.

Comment: the whole page is called search.php. I don't get to a generated page, becuase I get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Careful with PHP_SELF: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Comment: Pointers to alternate methods for beginners appreciated!...

Comment: I believe they meant the page with the form on it, not the results page.

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> Use that so you don't need shortags on (they are out of date)

Comment: `403 forbidden error` this error is not related to the php script at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid shortags, they are out of date, make sure to be using:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

What does the form's html look like when you load the page?

EDIT:
After reviewing my answer I'd like to rephrase it a bit, as they are not "out of date" per say, but they generally do cause problems (for those that don't know how to set up php fully), so for beginners I'd suggest avoiding them.

Comment: It doesn't get a form page, it refreshes the submit page. This suggests that the variable issue is fixed, but the connection between the php and mysql is not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is probably bad design, but I've always just hard-coded the script name in cases like that (so, just `action="search.php"`).

Comment: I tried this - and the submit page remains, the inputted values get wiped. There are no messages int he apache log. I guess this ssolves the problem I'm posing, but demonstrates that there is not a proper connection between the php and the mysql?...

Answer (score 0):

The $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] variable contains the full path of your php script, for example:
/your_server_path/your_file_name.php

Obviously, when launched, your script can't find the file because it's looking for something like
/your_server_path/your_server_path/your_file_name.php

Try to do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?='http://localhost'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I get the submit page being refreshed, so this seems to have fixed the manglement - I need to track down the connection error.

Comment: Put this line at the top of your php script
`ini_set("display_errors", "on");`

Comment: I get "Undefined variable: searching in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 4" which is now the "if ($searching =="yes")" line. Which I presume means the php is not parsing fully at kick off?

Comment: Where are you getting the $searching var from? Is it coming from the form? In this case you should use $_POST['searching']